# AttributeError: module 'elasticsearch' has no attribute 'helpers'

Tags: python, elasticsearch, attributeerror

I can't access the helpers of elasticsearch while trying to push data in bulk mode. Package installed :

```
pip freeze
elasticsearch==5.3.0
```

When in my code I try to call this method :

```
import elasticsearch

 client = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch([config['ES']['host']],
              connection_class=elasticsearch.RequestsHttpConnection,
              http_auth=(config['ES']['userName'], config['ES']['password']),
              port=int(config['ES']['hostPort']),
              use_ssl=True,
              verify_certs=False)
 elasticsearch.helpers.bulk(client, body)
```

I got the following error :

```
AttributeError: module 'elasticsearch' has no attribute 'helpers'
```

I'm using Python 3.5.1 and I have no problem reading data from my es cluster (without the use of helpers of course)

Comment: You need to do `import elasticsearch.helpers` as that's the way it's setup

Comment: I'm so stupid... thx mate :)

Comment: @JonClements how about adding this as an answer? It just helped me and I miss my upvote!

Answer (score 0):

As `@Jon Clements♦` correctly said,

```py
import elasticsearch.helpers
```

Is the correct way to import (therefore also the following works)

```py
from elasticsearch.helpers import scan
```

Enjoy